# Java source file unable to import already-compiled .class file from the same package

Tags: java, import, compilation, package, javac

**Directory Structure:**

- project

  - src

    - ticketing

      - entity

        - B.java
  - classes
  - given

    - C.class
  - compile.bat

**Issue:**

B and C belong to the same package called `ticketing.entity`, and C is already compiled. B needs to create a C object.

The first line of B's code is `package ticketing.entity;` (I assumed this would automatically import C as they are from the same package)

When I'm compiling in `compile.bat` file which is located in /project:
`javac -classpath given -d classes -sourcepath src src/ticketing/entity/B.java`
I received error: `cannot find symbol C`

Tried searching other threads but not sure what's wrong.

Comment: If C is in package foo.bar , it must also be in a subdirectory foo/bar

Comment: @GyroGearless thank you, this works!